# Angular 8 vs .NetCore WebAPI passing object as parameter

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

i am trying to hit .Net core WebApi from Angular 8, i am able to hit HttpGet methods but with post method while passing the register data as object it is not allowing . shows 400  issue. below is the code which was written to hit. please help.
RegisterCompoent.ts.

````
    this.userService.RegisterUser(this.userForm.value).subscribe((data) => {
      if (data) {
        alert("Registration successfull, go ahead and login");
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      }
    }, error => this.errormessage = error)
  }```
UserService.ts

 ```httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }
  RegisterUser(userDetails: any ):Observable<UserInfo> {
   
    // return this.http.post<UserInfo>('https://localhost:44322/api/User/RegisterUser/',userDetails,this.httpOptions)
    return this.http.post<UserInfo>('https://localhost:44322/api/User/RegisterUser/',JSON.stringify(userDetails),this.httpOptions)
  }```


.Net Core WebAPI RegisterUser

```[ApiController]
    [Route("api/User/[Action]")]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase
    {
        SqlRepository repository = new SqlRepository();
        [HttpPost]
        public int RegisterUser(UserInfo userInfo)
        {
            return repository.RegisterUsers(userInfo);
        }
        //[HttpPost]
        //public int RegisterUser([FromBody] string userInfo)
        //{
        //    UserInfo userDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserInfo>(userInfo.ToString());
        //    return repository.RegisterUsers(userDetails);
        //}```

please help the error it shows
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvTts.png
````

Comment: Try to remove your "JSON.stringify". You don't need this and you risk to change object to flat string. https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request

Comment: have the same error Gilsdav.     ``` RegisterUser(userDetails: UserInfo):Observable<UserInfo> {
   
    // return this.http.post<UserInfo>('https://localhost:44322/api/User/RegisterUser/',userDetails,this.httpOptions)
    return this.http.post<UserInfo>('https://localhost:44322/api/User/RegisterUser/',userDetails,this.httpOptions)
  }```      did i miss any thing

Comment: I want to know how it get the data of the form and the format of the data. From such a method, RegisterUser(userDetails: any) cannot know the specific format of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to replace type **any** in userDetails with string:

````
 RegisterUser(userDetails: string ):Observable<UserInfo> {
   
    return this.http.post<UserInfo>('https://localhost:44322/api/User/RegisterUser/',userDetails,this.httpOptions)
   }```
````

Answer (score 0):

Note: I did not test it but this should help you fix your issue.

Hi @SAI, in case the host/port you are trying to hit is correct I would try to do the following changes:

Remove the extra "/" at the end of the URL and also remove the JSON.stringify call

```
RegisterUser(userDetails: string ):Observable<UserInfo> {   
   return this.http.post<UserInfo>('https://localhost:44322/api/User/RegisterUser',userDetails, this.httpOptions)
}
```

Update the route configuration of your controller (also, check the comments I added to your action)

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
    SqlRepository repository = new SqlRepository();

    [HttpPost]
    public int RegisterUser(UserInfo userInfo)
    {
        // some details here. I am guessing this is an async operation
        // In which case I think you need to change this code also to wait
        // for the response and the return type of this action to Task<int>
        return repository.RegisterUsers(userInfo);
    }

 }
```